# Animating one CSS gradient to another with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, animation, gradient

I'd like to animate a gradient to another gradient. Here is my Codepen: https://codepen.io/EYT/pen/YvPEVQ . I used the mouse-distance as a variable to animate the gradient upwards.

This gradient should be the starting point and it shouldn't go lower then this (which it does at the moment when the mouse has a greater distance than 300px):

```
$element.css('background', 'linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(255, 66, 42, 1) '+(300-distance)/2+'%, rgba(217, 60, 40, 1) '+(305.24-distance)/2+'%, rgba(174, 54, 39, 1) '+(312.1-distance)/2+'%, rgba(136, 48, 37, 1) '+(319.52-distance)/2+'%, rgba(104, 44, 36, 1) '+(327.42-distance)/2+'%, rgba(78, 40, 35, 1) '+(335.92-distance)/2+'%, rgba(58, 37, 34, 1) '+(345.26-distance)/2+'%, rgba(44, 35, 33, 1) '+(355.86-distance)/2+'%, rgba(35, 33, 33, 1) '+(368.84-distance)/2+'%, rgba(33, 33, 33, 1) '+(390.96-distance)/2+'%)');
```

and on its way to 100px distance to the element it should be animated to this gradient:

```
$element.css('background', 'linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(255, 66, 42, 1) '+(300-distance)/2+'%, rgba(217, 60, 40, 1) '+(325.24-distance)/2+'%, rgba(174, 54, 39, 1) '+(352.1-distance)/2+'%, rgba(136, 48, 37, 1) '+(379.52-distance)/2+'%, rgba(104, 44, 36, 1) '+(407.42-distance)/2+'%, rgba(78, 40, 35, 1) '+(435.92-distance)/2+'%, rgba(58, 37, 34, 1) '+(465.26-distance)/2+'%, rgba(44, 35, 33, 1) '+(495.86-distance)/2+'%, rgba(35, 33, 33, 1) '+(528.84-distance)/2+'%, rgba(33, 33, 33, 1) '+(570.96-distance)/2+'%)');
```

Does someone have an idea of how to do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try converting px to % and use scaleY(${percent / 100)})

This is an example but you will have to adapt it for your needs:

```
(function() {
    var element = document.getElementById("element");
    var onMouseMove = function(evt) {
      const percent = ((evt.clientY / document.documentElement.scrollHeight) * 100);
      element.style.transform = `scaleY(${(percent / 100)}`;

    }
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
})();
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rKadWB?editors=1111

Comment: Thank you for the demo and for your help, but it's not quiet working for me. I think I need to find another way of achieving this effect.